# Return date 7 days passed target date | SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

I am trying to get all tickets that are still open passed a specified 'closure' date by 7 days and the 'bill date' is passed 7 days. Tickets look like:

```
Work Order: Description:     Status:     Task:     End Date:     Billed On:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INC1234     Broken Monitor   OPEN        1         03/25/2021    03/25/2021
INC1235     No Audio         OPEN        1         04/03/2021    04/01/2021
```

In theory, the query would only return `INC1234` as this ticket meets the criteria. The Ticket Number, Description, Billed On and Status are stored on one table, the Task is stored on another, and the End Date is stored on a third.

What I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    wo.proposal AS 'Work Order',
    wo.description AS 'Description',
    wo.status_code AS 'Status',
    phs.task AS 'Task',
    wo.act_end_dt AS 'End Date',
    fnd.tranx_date AS 'Billed On'
FROM
    table1 wo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table2 phs ON (wo.proposal = phs.proposal)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table3 fnd ON (wo.proposal = fnd.proposal)
WHERE
    wo.status_code = 'OPEN'
    AND phs.act_end_dt <= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
    AND fnd.tranx_date <= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Sometimes multiple bills are charged to one ticket. This query seems to only be grabbing the very first transaction billed rather than the latest. (So if it had a bill on March 23 and one on March 31, it will only grab March 23 which isn't correct) I can't seem to get it to grab the latest bill date and go 7 days from then.

Comment: `left join` doesn't make sense here, probably should be `inner join`. Why are you `distinct` ing? It's not grabbing the first transaction, it's grabbing all transactions that are within those dates. What you need is something like an `exists` over the transaction table checking if there are any for a given `proposal` that are before the date.

Comment: @Charlieface Sometimes it will return the same ticket more than once. Like right now I run it and it shows one ticket the the same Ticket#, Description, Status, Task #, End Date & Trans Date - so I was trying to stop that but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your joins. Telling us what the tables actually are and how they relate to each other (primary and foreign keys) would help a lot

Answer (score 1):

Work Order, description, status code and end date come from the same table.
Task comes from another table. Billed On comes from another table.

You want to get the latest transaction of the corresponding table for a ticket number. One solution can be to define a view which will contain the subset of that table in which each ticket appears only once with its maximum date. Then you can use that view in your query; simply replace table3 by that view.

The view can be written as an aggregation:

```
select proposal, max(tranx_date) from table3 group by proposal;
```

Assuming that the view is named table3_view then your query could be written as you did by replacing table3 by table3_view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
wo.proposal AS 'Work Order',
wo.description AS 'Description',
wo.status_code AS 'Status',
phs.task AS 'Task',
wo.act_end_dt AS 'End Date',
fnd.tranx_date AS 'Billed On'
FROM
table1 wo
LEFT OUTER JOIN
table2 phs ON (wo.proposal = phs.proposal)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
table3_view fnd ON (wo.proposal = fnd.proposal)
WHERE
wo.status_code = 'OPEN'
AND
phs.act_end_dt <= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
AND
fnd.tranx_date <= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand. Do I take the ```select proposal, max(tranx_date) from table3 group by proposal;``` and add it to the beginning of the query so I can use ```table3_view``` after the Left Join?

Comment: A view can be created like so for example: `create view table3_view as select proposal, max(tranx_date) from table3 group by proposal;` - try to use that.

Comment: I was able to create the view, however it is still returning every transaction entry rather than just the latest one. Example, it returns me a single ticket, but shows me the ticket 9 times because there were 9 times it was billed.

Comment: This might be related to the way you make the join as others pointed out; I assumed you did it right and showed a way to get the latest ticket transaction from table3. I believe that you need to provide better information in order to get better help. If you don't mind please describe the three tables (columns, types and primary keys).